# mi proyecto maven de spring boot se crea con un error en el archivo pom.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Como pueden ver en esta imagen al crear mi proyecto maven el archivo pom.xml que viene por defecto trae el siguiente error: [imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBhvz.png)

PD:
Ya intente crear otro proyecto pero siempre trae el mismo error.

Comment: Buenas, tu pregunta esta pesimamente redactada, lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Has probado crear un proyecto con Spring Initializer? Puede ser una variante para garantizar que la estructura del proyecto sea la adecuada. Por otro lado, intenta crear una proyecto utilizando una versión de Spring Boot un poco más antigua o verifica los repositorios de spring boot a los que apunta el pom.xml.

Comment: Tengo proyectos en donde esa linea del pom igual me la marca con error pero eso no quiere decir que el proyecto no funcione, tu proyecto levanta ?